# How do you use environment variables in vxWorks?

Tags: vxworks

In a vxWorks Real-Time process, you can pass environment variables as one of the parameter of the **main** routine.

How do you use the environment variables in the kernel context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call this directly from the VxWorks shell:

```
putenv "<VARIABLE NAME>=<VALUE>"
```

replace  with your environment variable name and  with the value you want to set it to.

Answer (score 3):

Vxworks environment variable support is provided by the envLib.

use **putenv("VAR=value")** to set the value of the environment variable.

use **char* var = getenv("VAR")** to retrieve the value.

Comment: That was a pretty quick answer to your own question!